# Trouble with First Responder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, fonts, interface-builder

I've had some trouble implementing some shortcuts in a document based application (i.e. Bold, Italic etc) available here:

[Connecting Menu Items in Document Based Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892705/connecting-menu-items-in-document-based-applications)

The issue is that the method described disconnects the actual 'Bold' menu item from the Font Manager, and replaces it with my action I created (in this case, `boldIt`). Because there can be only one sent action, it is replaced, not added. How can I overcome this? Very frustrating. If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't have a menu trigger two actions, there's two good ways to approach this:

1) Have your `boldIt:` action call the appropriate method in the `NSFontManager` when it's done with it's work. The drawback here is that whatever `boldIt:` is called on needs to know about the Font Manager as well.

2) Subclass NSFontManager and override `addFontTrait:` to include your desired behaviour when 'Bold' is selected, and then call the original method on the super class with `[super addFontTrait:sender]`.